# How do I navigate and select menu options when using GMAMEUI?

Tags: 11.10, package-management

I am using 11.10. I installed mame and gmameui from the software center.

Downloaded a couple of ROMS. When I try to play a game I hit TAB to find out the key bindings.  I get a menu shown (Input General, Input This Game etc) but dont seem to be able to select any options or navigate the menu.  Any ideas ?

Comment: ok I figured it out.  If the mouse point is pointing exactly inside the menu area then moving the mouse up / down will change the selected menu and double clicking on an item will move to the next menu under that. Whats wrong with plain old UP/DOWN/LEFT/RIGHT/ENTER ?

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This question was solved by the OP:

> ok I figured it out. If the mouse point is pointing exactly inside the
>   menu area then moving the mouse up / down will change the selected
>   menu and double clicking on an item will move to the next menu under
>   that.